# Take commands from a file from command line

Tags: java, file, command-line, linked-list, java.util.scanner

How do I implement the following?

I have a LinkedList list. list is initialized by command line and takes 2 arguments.
the command line for our LinkedList implementation is

```
java LinkedList maxSize fileName
```

fileName is a .txt file. The first one is as follows:

```
input1.txt
insert 10
Insert 15
inSert 20
delete 35
insert 35
find 12
find 35
delete 20
```

our outputs are:

```
insert 10 true
Insert 15 true
inSert 20 true
delete 35 false
insert 35 true
find 12   false
find 35   true
delete 20 true
```

What this means is we ignore casing for characters and only care about commands insert, delete, and find. The fileName has our command (method) to run in LinkedList.java and gives us our key. The commandLine initializes our LinkedList to a set maxSize and passes in input files to test against.

My question is: how do I read in the command from fileName and read the key so I can execute the appropriate method call? I'm thinking of using scanner. We can assume all commands are one line and valid syntax. We can also assume maxSize will be big enough to reflect the given input/output files.

Comment: Why not scanner? you can convert the strings to one case to ignore case.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking scanner, but I was curious if there was a better way. Part of the assignment is creating the most efficient algorithms

Comment: I dont know about efficiency; scanner is to me the simplest. Of course, its also the only one i know.

Comment: `Scanner` is part of the default library, so you have a portability advantage. Speed would only be a few milliseconds different. Use `Scanner`.

Comment: Well I guess I can do a scanner, but I'm not sure how implement each command yet.

Comment: Ideally Scanner would read a line, cast it to the method with the key,
and read the next line

Comment: Not quite @Evan. His program is described as saving the contents of .txt to his list. Mine takes a list of commands and keys from .txt and implements them. The LL is the first part, I still have to do the same thing for an array and SkipList as well actually

I stumbled on `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))`
if this might work?

Comment: @user3466773 Ok, I believe I have a solution I typed up. will post momentarily.

Comment: @user3466773 If my answer does not resolve, check the link here, it's a very similar problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859462/using-a-text-file-to-carry-commands-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this: I used a very similar method for a project I had to do using linked-lists and reading commands from a file. Modify as needed. The basic concept is that you loop, reading each command line until you reach the termination command/condition, then print out the results or whatever you need to do for your specific instance.

Also, here is another useful link that is nearly exactly what you need: [Using a text file to carry commands in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859462/using-a-text-file-to-carry-commands-in-java?lq=1)

```
    boolean done = false;
    // Loop runs as long as done != true
    while (!done) {
        line = sc.nextLine();   // Store data gathered from file into String
        String [] tokens = line.split(" "); // Split the string using space as delimiter

        // Switch for processing commands received
        switch (tokens[0]) {

        // Print name followed by newline
        case "N": {
                System.out.println("Evan Clay Bechtol");
                break;
            }

        // Create a memory object of size s
        case "C": {
                memory = new Memory(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])); // Create a new Memory object
                break;
            }

        // End of data file, print newline and exit
        case "E": {
                System.out.println();
                done = true;    // Break the loop, end the program
                break;
            }

        // Add segment of size 'u' and lifetime 'v' and print confirmation record
        case "A": {
                int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                int lifeTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                timeOfDay++;

                memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);

                // Boolean controls whether confirmation is printed.
                while (!memory.place(size, timeOfDay, lifeTime, true)) {
                    timeOfDay++;
                    memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                    } // End while
                placements++;

                // Print confirmation message
                //System.out.println("Added segment of size: " + size + "\t" + "lifeTime: " + lifeTime + "\t" + "Time of Departure: " + (lifeTime + timeOfDay));
                break;  
            }

        // Print the current segments in the list
        case "P": {
                System.out.println ();
                memory.printLayout();
                //System.out.println ("End at time: " + timeOfDay);
                break;
            }

        case "R": {
                int size = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]); // Size
                memory = new Memory(size);
                int minSegSize = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);   // Minimum seg. size
                int maxSegSize = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);   // Maximum seg. size
                int maxLifeTime = Integer.parseInt(tokens[4]);  // Maximum lifetime of segs.
                int numSegs = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]);      // Number of segs. to simulate
                timeOfDay = 0;
                placements = 0;
                Random ran = new Random (); // "Random" number generator

                while (placements < numSegs) {
                    timeOfDay++;
                    memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                    int newSegSize = minSegSize + ran.nextInt(maxSegSize - minSegSize + 1);
                    int newSegLifetime = 1 + ran.nextInt(maxLifeTime);
                    totalSpaceTime += newSegSize * newSegLifetime;

                    while (!memory.place(newSegSize, timeOfDay, newSegLifetime, false)) {
                        timeOfDay++;
                        memory.removeSegmentsDueToDepart(timeOfDay);
                    } // End while
                    placements++;
                } // End while

                // Print final summary of execution
                meanOccupancy = totalSpaceTime / (timeOfDay);
                System.out.printf ("Number of placements made =  %6d", placements);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.printf ("Mean occupancy of memory  = %8.2f", meanOccupancy);
                System.out.println();
            }
        } // End switch
    } // End while
    sc.close();
```